# Series Dependencies

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

If i have a series
$$
a_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{b^nn!}(n+c)^2
$$

and another series
$$
c_n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}(n+c)^2
$$

Is there some way to find some $f(x)$ so that

$$
a_n = f(x,b)c_n
$$

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that what you called $a_n$ actually does not depend on $n$, but on $x$, $b$ and $c$. The same applied to $c_n$. Now, we have:
$$ a(x,b,c):= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{ 2n} }{b^n n!} (n+c)^2     $$
and
$$ r(x,c):= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{ 2n} }{ n!} (n+c)^2     $$
Then, it is clear that:
$$ a(x,b,c) = r \left(\frac{ x}{ \sqrt{ b}}, c \right )  $$
where we assume $b >0$.

Comment: Thank you, great answer!